# syntax error (missing operator) in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to use the following query, however it is saying missing operator and syntax error. This problem is with ms access.

```
select s.student_id, e.average_second_year_marks, e.average_third_year_marks, e.overall_marks
from students s
join
(
  select student_id,
    avg(case when program_year_when_enrolled = 'Second' then marks_obtained end)
      as average_second_year_marks,
    avg(case when program_year_when_enrolled = 'Third' then marks_obtained end)
      as average_third_year_marks,
    (
     (sum(case when program_year_when_enrolled = 'Second' then marks_obtained end) * 1.0) +
     (sum(case when program_year_when_enrolled = 'Third' then marks_obtained end) * 2.0)
    ) / 3.0 as overall_marks
  from enrollment
  group by student_id
) e on e.student_id = s.student_id
where s.course_current_status = 'Graduated-2017'
```

Comment: If this about Microsoft Access, why did you tag MySQL and Postgres then? I removed the tags. Please only add tags that are relevant.

Comment: MS Access doesn't support the 'CASE' statement, you will need to convert those into `iif` statements.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent MS Access query would be more like this:

```
select s.student_id, e.average_second_year_marks,
       e.average_third_year_marks, e.overall_marks
from students as s inner join
     (select student_id,
             avg(iif(program_year_when_enrolled = "Second", marks_obtained, NULL)) as average_second_year_marks,
             avg(iif(program_year_when_enrolled = "Third", marks_obtained, NULL)) as average_third_year_marks
             (1.0 * avg(iif(program_year_when_enrolled = "Second", marks_obtained, NULL)) +
              2.0 * avg(iif(program_year_when_enrolled = "Third", marks_obtained, NULL)) 
             ) / 3.0 as overall_marks
     from enrollment
     group by student_id
    ) as e 
    on e.student_id = s.student_id
where s.course_current_status = "Graduated-2017";
```

Comment: It's saying syntax error in join clause but when I use another join such as a left join or outer join it then says syntax errors in join operation. Can you please help what I should do with it.